# List of available environment variables for cdk CLI?

Tags: aws-cdk

Is there a list of environment variables that can be set for the AWS CDK CLI? I see there is a `CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP` at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html and a `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION`  at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html.

Is there any documentation around the configuration that can be set by environment variables? For example, can I set the qualifier by an environment variable?